# Is it possible to dllexport (and then dllimport) function written in assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly, dll, visual-c++-2012

I have large C++ project, containing few modules - all of them are compiled to dynamic libraries. I target multiple platforms, including Windows, Linux and MacOSX.

Profiling tests revealed some critical points, in which I was able to get huge performance gain, for example: hash computing, some vector operations etc. I implemented this functionality in assembly using SSE/MMX.

Everything was fine, until I switched back to x64 target in Visual C++, where inline assembly is not permitted. And I'm stuck. Also, these functions are used in other modules as well.

Basically, what I am trying to achieve, is to implement some functions, that reside inside DLL in assembly. I tried this:

**Api.h**

```
extern "C" void DLL_API __stdcall sample_fun(/*args*/);
```

**Api.asm**

```
sample_fun PROC public ;args
.....
sample_fun ENDP
```

This obviously will not work, because of name mangling.

I also tried this:

**Api.h**

```
void DLL_API sample_fun(/*args*/);
```

**Api.cpp**

```
extern "C" __stdcall sample_fun_impl(/*args*/).

void DLL_API sample_fun(/*args*/)
{
  return sample_fun_impl(/*args*/);
}
```

**Api.asm**

```
sample_fun_impl PROC public ;args
.....
sample_fun_impl ENDP
```

In this case, I am still getting linker error about unresolved external symbol (sample_fun_impl), which is weird, because it is actually a private function, called only from within the DLL.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to ?

Comment: At least your second version should work. Examine the linker error and see what symbol it is looking for. Don't know about visual studio, but some toolchains like to prefix symbols with an underscore.

Comment: Why don't you just wrap your assembly code in a C function. If you are worried about performance you can do an inline C function.

Comment: @user1998698 This exactly what it looks like now. This is what we call an 'inline assembly' - asm code wrapped inside a C/C++ function. However, this is not supported when compiling code for ARM or x64 processors: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93.aspx.

Comment: Are you compiling all of that for x64? I'm asking because for x64 `__stdcall` is ignored and there's no name mangling for `extern "C"` functions, as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about x64. `__stdcall` is just an example. I tried `__cdecl` as well, with no result. And yes, I checked whether is not a problem with an underscore prepended to `__cdecl` functions' names.

Comment: As I said, you shouldn't need any of those calling convention specifiers in x64 mode. Are you assembling with `ml64`?

Comment: I have `.asm` file attached directly to project (`.vcxproj`, Visual Studio 2012) and enabled MASM project build customization. So I am certainly sure, that in x64 target, VS uses `ml64` to parse `.asm` files.

Comment: I've just replicated your second setup locally and it built and ran fine, calling a simple assembly function taking two `long long`s and returning `long long` (by the way, your `sample_fun_impl` prototype lacks a return type). However, for some reason, the default target platform was "Mixed Platforms", which actually called `ml`. I had to change it to `x64` to get a full 64-bit build, which used `ml64` and linked fine. Could this be your issue?

Comment: @bogdan It wasn't my issue, my platform was set correctly. To make an additional quick check, I made a typo error inside `.asm` source and I got: `error MSB3721: The command "ml64.exe [...] exited with code 1.` So this is fine. **But**: I also did a minimal replication of my code and found origin of all my problems. And it was your suggestion about calling conventions that helped me solve this. I will provide my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem has been solved. Here is a minimal example of what I wanted with some explanations:

**Asx.h**

```
namespace Asx
{
#if ASX_PLATFORM_IS64BIT //This is resolved using 'ifdef _M_X64'
    extern ASX_DLL_API ULONGLONG roundup_pow2_64(ULONGLONG value);
#else
    extern ASX_DLL_API DWORD roundup_pow2_32(DWORD value);
#endif
}
```

**Asx.cpp**

```
#include "Asx.h"

#if ASX_PLATFORM_IS64BIT
extern "C" ULONGLONG __cdecl roundup_pow2_64_impl(ULONGLONG value);
#else
extern "C" DWORD __cdecl roundup_pow2_32_impl(DWORD value);
#endif

namespace Asx
{

#if ASX_PLATFORM_IS64BIT
    ULONGLONG roundup_pow2_64(ULONGLONG value)
    {
        return roundup_pow2_64_impl(value);
    }
#else
    DWORD roundup_pow2_32(DWORD value)
    {
        return roundup_pow2_32_impl(value);
    }
#endif

}
```

**Asx_asm_impl.asm**

```
IFNDEF ASX_PLATFORM_IS64BIT
.686P
.MODEL FLAT, C
.XMM
ENDIF

.CODE

IFDEF ASX_PLATFORM_IS64BIT

roundup_pow2_64_impl PROC public, value:QWORD
//Implementation
roundup_pow2_64_impl ENDP

ELSE

roundup_pow2_32_impl PROC public, value:DWORD
//Implementation
roundup_pow2_32_impl ENDP

ENDIF

END
```

What was wrong?

1) I did not take into account, that calling conventions are treated differently in x64, however accidentally this didn't cause any problems.

2) At some point, I noticed, that functions marked `__cdecl` are searched by linker using their name prepended with an underscore. I made `dumpbin` of problematic DLL and it was there - but indeed with an underscore at the beginning! So I left its declaration as it was and changed its name from `roundup_pow2_32_impl` to `_roundup_pow2_32_impl` and at the same time, I added `MODEL FLAT, C`.

3) I used IFDEF/IFNDEF inside `.asm` file. But I assumed, that all defines visible to `cl` will be also visible to `ml`/`ml64`. Wrong. Only after manually adding required constants everything started to work (`.asm` file properties -> Microsoft Macro Assembler -> General -> Preprocessor Definitions).

I guess after trying and trying many different solutions, everything turned into one, big mess. Clean setup worked perfectly:

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "../Asx/Header.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
#if ASX_PLATFORM_IS64BIT
    ULONGLONG v = Asx::roundup_pow2_64(4000);
#else
    DWORD v = Asx::roundup_pow2_32(4000);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Result in both Win32 and x64: `4096`.

And big thanks for **bogdan**! Without his hint about calling convention specifiers on x64, I wouldn't solve this.